# git: How can I merge my working file with the latest one

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I'm new to git, and still having a lot of trouble.

Say that I'm working on `a.cpp`. I modified some code in `a.cpp`. And, that change is not ready to commit or push.

Then, other people also made a change in `a.cpp`.

In SVN/CVS, checking out do either a merge or conflict.

I thought that `git pull` does the same thing.

But, it seems that `git pull` doesn't merge/conflict. Is this correct behavior?

Also, `git checkout` just simply rewrites `a.cpp`, losing all my changes.

Is there any easy way to pull the latest version and perform merge/conflict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you pull, [stash your changes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing). Then after your pull, you can pop your stashed changes and rebase them on the newest commit.

first stash all your changes

```
git stash
```

You can view your stashes by running `stash show`. If you haven't stashed anything before you should now see one stash. You can now pull without overwriting your changes:

```
git pull
```

Now remove your changes from the stash and apply them to the currently checked out version:

```
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to commit NOT push. Then rebase from remote.